# Linq query to reference entity

Tags: linq

How can I reference an entity?? I know that in  this line

```
if(!db.users.any(u => u.customer =="mike")
```

(db.users) refers to the users table.. So now  i need to reference an iqueryable in a .cs

```
public IQueryable<Address_List_NEW> GetAddress_List_NEWs(string Customer)
{ 
    return this.DataContext.Address_List_NEWs;
}
```

why does this not work??

```
if(!Address_List_NEW.any(u => u.Customer == "mike")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return a strongly typed `IQueryable<T>`, otherwise Linq doesn't know the properties of the object you are accessing:

```
public IQueryable<Address_List_NEW> GetAddress_List_NEWs() 
{ 
   return this.DataContext.Address_List_NEWs; 
}
```

Keep in mind you are not using the parameter you pass in, so I removed it - is this what you intended? (Right now this method is not doing much of anything)

Then you should be able to do:

```
var adressList = GetAddress_List_NEWs();
if(!adressList.Any(u => u.Customer == "mike"))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Address_List_NEW` is the name of a class, not an `IQueryable<Address_List_NEW>` so you cannot call `Any` off of it.

Based on your function signature, it kind of looks like you want to write this:

```
public bool CustomerHasAddress(string Customer) 
{ 
   return !this.DataContext.Address_List_NEWs.Any(u => u.Customer == Customer); 
}
```

Or possibly something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Address_List_NEW> GetAddress_List_NEWsForCustomer(string Customer) 
{ 
   return this.DataContext.Address_List_NEWs.Where(u => u.Customer == Customer); 
}
```

Then you could call `GetAddress_List_NEWsForCustomer("mike").Any()`

Or even something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Address_List_NEW> GetAddress_List_NEWs() 
{ 
   return this.DataContext.Address_List_NEWs; 
}
```

From which you could call `GetAddress_List_NEWs.Any(u => u.Customer == "mike")`